# An error ocurred while starting the kernel (spyder)

Tags: python, spyder

i get the message on my console:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uCt7.png)

hopefully anyone would understand or have seen similar errors.
i tried restarting, updating and its not doing anything

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/mac/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
File "/Users/mac/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "/Users/mac/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site‑packages/spyder_kernels/console/__main__.py", line 11, in 
start.main()
File "/Users/mac/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site‑packages/spyder_kernels/console/start.py", line 279, in main
import_spydercustomize()
File "/Users/mac/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site‑packages/spyder_kernels/console/start.py", line 39, in import_spydercustomize
import spydercustomize
File "/Users/mac/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site‑packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 27, in 
from IPython.core.getipython import get_ipython
File "/Users/mac/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site‑packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 55, in 
from .terminal.embed import embed
File "/Users/mac/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site‑packages/IPython/terminal/embed.py", line 17, in 
from IPython.terminal.ipapp import load_default_config
File "/Users/mac/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site‑packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 28, in 
from IPython.core.magics import (
File "/Users/mac/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site‑packages/IPython/core/magics/__init__.py", line 18, in 
from .code import CodeMagics, MacroToEdit
File "/Users/mac/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site‑packages/IPython/core/magics/code.py", line 23, in 
from urllib.request import urlopen
File "/Users/mac/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 88, in 
import http.client
File "/Users/mac/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 72, in 
import email.message
File "/Users/mac/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/email/message.py", line 10, in 
import uu
File "/Users/mac/uu.py", line 9, in 
y=int(input('guess the number '))
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you copy and paste the trace of your error into the original question? This will help others see what problem you are having easier.

Comment: yes, now i understood how to add the error message, thanks for the tip

Comment: Could you also add the relevant code where you are getting the error (around line 9)? It looks like it could be that you forgot to close a parenthesis or something like that, although there is no way to tell without the relevant code.

Comment: i actually have the temp file open, when this started i have multiple files open and the codes are free of error i ran them with sublime to check

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This error happens because you named one of your files (in this case `/Users/mac/uu.py`) with the same name as a Python standard library module (in this case the [uu](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/uu.py) module).

You can fix this by removing or renaming `/Users/mac/uu.py` to something other.

Comment: I also want to add that this doesn't happen with the latest versions of Spyder and IPython (which the OP seems to have) unless he/she *explicitly* added `/Users/mac` to his/her `PYTHONPATH`. At least that's the only explanation I can find for this.